# Automated email replies in OS x mail for specific hours

Tags: apple-mail

I am trying to create an automated email response for after hours emails.  But I am not seeing how to do it or if it is possible with OS x mail

Answer (score 2):

### Create an Automatic Reply Message

Adding an automatic reply with OS X Mail is easy. Mail must be running for rules to apply for new messages and Mail preferences must be set to check mail automatically or periodically.

To create an automated email response, select `Mail`->`Preferences...` from the menu bar and click the `Rules` tab.

- Click the <kbd>Add Rule</kbd> button, and give the rule a name.

[image: Add Rule]

- Select conditions from the pull-down menus. Click <kbd>+</kbd> to add conditions. You might want the rule to apply to a specific account or a subject.

  - While you're testing your automatic response, add a condition for the incoming message subject to be a unique value such as "** TEST TEST TEST **". This will prevent other messages from receiving the automatic response.
  - Remove the condition for the subject when you're done testing.
- Select the "Reply to Message" action, and click the <kbd>Reply message text...</kbd> button. Enter your reply message. You may want a second action to flag the message.
- Click the <kbd>OK</kbd> button.

**This is important!** When Mail asks "Do you want to apply your rules to messages in selected mailboxes?" click the <kbd>Don't Apply</kbd> button. The new rule will always be applied to new messages, but you don't want to automatically reply to all the messages you've already received.

Test the Auto Reply rule by sending a message to yourself.

### Turn the Automatic Response On and Off

You can always check if a rule is active. To manually control your automatic response, select `Mail`->`Preferences...` from the menu bar and click the `Rules` tab. Click the Active check box to turn the rule on and off.

[image: Enable or Disable Rule]

### Scheduling the Automatic Response

The automatic response rule can be turned on and off with AppleScript. OS X has various ways to run repeating tasks depending on your needs.

This AppleScript will make a rule named `Auto Reply` active:

```
tell application "Mail" to set enabled of rule "Auto Reply" to true
```

To make the rule inactive, use:

```
tell application "Mail" to set enabled of rule "Auto Reply" to false
```